# attaching to Unix shared segment

Tags: memory, root, shared-memory

Can a UNIX program running as root attach to a shared memory segment created by another user with permissions allowing access only to creator?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the test I was running before asking the question did not show a clear behavior.

Tried again with gdb -- it appears that a root program can attach to a partition created by another user even if that partition's permissions allow access only to its creator.